# Are there different types of zombies?

Tags: dayz-2012

Some zombies stand upright and some are crawling around on all fours.  Aside from aesthetics, is there any difference between these zombies?  Are there other zombie types I haven't seen?

Comment: I've seen some that crawl prone. Not sure whether or not they can actually get up and run of they see you though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://www.dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Zombies), there are three types of zombies:

> **Walkers**: These zombies stand upright and walk slowly. They run very fast in zigzags at the player and are often hard to hit. They are the most common zombie type.
>
> **Hoppers**: These zombies are crouched and hop towards the player at a medium speed flailing their arms once agroed, they can be hard to see and often blend in with grass on approach.
>
> **Crawlers**: These zombies are the rarest and are in prone position, they can be very difficult to see in the grass and are the quickest of zombies when they arn't aggroed. However, this is the slowest zombie when they are aggroed.

There will also be dogs in the future:

> Meanwhile, Hall has confirmed that dogs are coming to DayZ - in all likelihood, they'll be German Shepherds, he said.

Comment: Some zombies have different drop rates than others.  Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe so. However there seems to be talk of implementing infected dogs in the future.